# why centos 7 firewalld status is active,but firewall-cmd is not runing?

Tags: centos, centos7, firewalld

Here is my infomation:

[image]

When I reload firewall-cmd,the xshell disconnect to Vps.It seems like the server break down.I have to reboot server to reconnect.

Thank you in advance.I am newbie for centos.

Comment: There is another problem,I can not connect to mysql by Navicat and Mysql Work Bench,but the command line is OK.I think it maybe has something to do with firewalld,but I don't know exact reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql WorkBench can not connect to database because my ip has changed.I need to grant the current ip to the database server.